# docker-compose: port forward localhost:80 inside a docker container to host port 80

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a situation where I need to let several jobs inside a single docker container orchestrated by docker-compose 1.16.1 communicate with a legacy system.

The legacy system runs in a vagrant box on the same host and binds to three ports (7880, 58608, and 58709).   I understand that the default configuration of docker allows accessing the host as 172.17.0.1, but for obscure technical reasons due to network differences I need the host port available on "localhost".

So, how do I make "localhost port 7880" as seen from inside the docker container port forward to the host port 7880?

I have full control of the docker instance and invocation.

Comment: `localhost` resolves to the loopback address (127.0.0.1) of the container itself. Changing this might brake things. Have you considered any other option? For example adding an entry to your `/etc/hosts`, something like `172.17.0.1 my_docker_host`... You will then access your legacy system at `my_docker_host:7880`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `network_mode: host` section to your docker-compose file and share localhost with containers and host.

Comment: Thank you.  Apparently I missed this configuration nugget when learning about docker networking a while back.